# Loop on excel rows in different Excel worksheets C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file myexcel.xlsx which has multiple worksheets. All worksheets has the same columns names in the first row. One column is called ID and another column is called Total. I am going through each row in every worksheet then I wonder how I can then check the columns ID if it exists in any other row in the same or other worksheet. If the ID is not found somewhere else then the total will be only equal to the Total column of this row, but if the same ID exists in another row in the same/other worksheet then I want to add the Total column of the other row as well then ignore all these rows of the same ID in the for loop so that they are not repeated.

```
            Excel.Application myapp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook myworkbook = myapp(@"myexcel.xlsx");
            for (int i = 1; i <= myworkbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
            {
                Excel._Worksheet myworksheet = myworkbook.Worksheets[i];
                Excel.Range myrange = myworksheet.UsedRange;
                int myrowCount = myrange.Rows.Count;
            }
```

Comment: you need to clarify what you mean by "then ignore all these rows of the same ID" Do you mean you only want to use the ID once per worksheet?  You say ignore but you say also keep track of the total for same ID across worksheets.

Comment: I'd consider splitting this into two problems. One is creating some sort of class that can hold this data, and writing code to read all the data from the spreadsheet. Maybe you end up with two lists of some object. Then separately figure out how to operate with the data. What you're doing will work but it's harder because you're figuring out two things at once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the correct syntax for working with Excel sheets, so I'll give you a basic example for what I think you are asking. You'll have to adjust the code so it works, but if you want to aggregate (get the sum) of the "Total" in all the rows with the same "ID" you should be able to do something like this:

```
var totalsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

for (var ws = 0; ws < worksheets.Count; ws++)
{
    var worksheet = worksheets[ws];
    for (var row = 0; row < worksheet.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        var id = worksheet.Rows[row]["ID"];
        var total = worksheet.Rows[row]["Total"];
        if (totalsDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            totalsDictionary[id] += total;
        }
        else
        {
            totalsDictionary.Add(id, total);
        }
    }
}

// totalsDictionary now contains the sum of Totals for each ID
```